# How to figure the angle to drill from an above ground carport to basement next to it?

Tags: drill, angle

Okay, so not the best drawing below (The wall between basement + 1st floor, and carport, should have been depicted as thicker for this illustration, for one)...

.... However I need to drill a hole from the left wall of the carport (Car is pictured showing it's back) through to beside the Electrical panel, so I can then (housed in conduit) run 6AWG (Copper / 75°C; If it isn't cheaper to go larger in aluminium or a different temparture rating in either) from a socket in the carport to a breaker in the panel.

How does one work out the angle to do so when the real roof (not drop ceiling) is likely not parallel with the floor of the carport, but one is not sure by how much it is off, so one can use pythagorean theorem to work out the angle to drill at?

[image]

Comment: Generally you won’t “drill at an angle”.  Normally you drill straight through.  Normally you can get an idea because typically there are other things (pipes/wires) that also come straight thru.  Please post actual picture of the location inside and out, and we can help you much better.

Comment: If you can't get a good line of sight to drill directly consider longer options. For example, you could drill into the first floor and then down into the basement. You might do this into a space where the conduit in the 1st floor is not an eyesore like the back of a closet. Having conduit running along some length of your basement or car port is not usually a big deal to take advantage of this if you need to.

Comment: re-draw the picture, and include the thickness of the walls and ceiling this time

Answer (score 1):

use a water level to find matching level spots inside and outside of the basement

get a large jar of water

get some tubing 1/8" to 1/4" long enough to reach from the carport, through a window or door onto the basement floor and up the wall of the basement

fill the tubing with water, put one end in the jar of water (loop it through a large metal washer to keep it submerged)

plug the other end with your thumb and drag the the tube into the basement

hold the tubing high against the wall and release your thumb

the water level in the tubing will settle to the same level as the water in the jar

[image]

Comment: +1 Ingenuitive idea! Will give it a try and return here to mark as answer once done, as I am sure this will work.